# About xiaomi push service at server aspect

Tags: android

```
Request URL: https://api.xmpush.xiaomi.com/v2/message/alias Request 
Method: POST 
Form Data: alias=test_alias1 &description=notification description &payload=this+is+xiaomi+push &restricted_package_name=com.xiaomi.mipushdemo &title=notification title &notify_type=2 &time_to_live=1000 &pass_through=0 &extra.notify_effect=2 &extra.intent_uri=intent:#Intent;action=com.a.b.shot;end
```

Above is the API documentation for how to post the arguments to a server for self-defined behavior about clicking the notification.

Here is my question: How can I open the MainActivity(com.app.MainActvity),that is, how can I change the "`extra.intent_uri=intent:#Inetent;action=com.a.b.shot;end`" to meet my need?

Hope anyone can do me this favor, thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing the intent to ;action=com.app.MainActvity;

Comment: yes, i tried, but it didn't work at my situation. thx

Comment: i finally get the right one. It should be "extra.intent_uri=intent:#Intent;component=com.app/.MainActivity;end"